# How to pass a variable to custom validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a custom validator that resides in the AppServiceProvider. The boot method contains a DB method that should accept the first patameter passed into the validator as the table name. When I manually fill out the table name, it works but when the first parameter is passed, I run into this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'server1.{users}' 
doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `{users}` where `email` = 
mail@mail.com and `STORE_ID` = 2)
```

Here's my service provider code:

```
public function boot()
{
  Validator::extend('uniqueForStore', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $count = DB::table($parameters[0])->where($attribute, $value)->where('STORE_ID', config('constants.STORE_ID'))->count();
      return $count === 0;
  });
}
```

This is where the problem lies:

```
DB::table($parameters[0])
```

Here's my register user form request code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => "uniqueForStore:{users}",
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ];
}
```

Comment: You cant just set "uniqueForStore:users"?

Comment: Thank you @PatrykWoziński . It works. If you add the answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your validation rules as below - just remove brackets for unique value (users):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => "uniqueForStore:users",
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ];
}
```